# When using pygame and pyinstaller I get an error telling me "excpected str, bytes or os.Pathlike object, not BytesIO

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I've been making a small game in pygame where you click on a rectangle, it disappears with a small animation and then pops up in a new random place on the screen. I used pyinstaller to make the file executable so my friends could try out what I made, but when I made the exe with pyinstaller (file) --onefile --noconsole and then opened it in the same folder as my assets folder, this error pops up.
Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: *The same folder as my assets folder*. That is not how `pyinstaller` works. It has to pack your assets *inside* the executable, and extract them to a temporary folder at runtime. To tell it what to do, create a `.spec` file. The docs explain how.

Comment: ok, I'll try that :). Should've read the documentation I guess

Comment: @BoarGules But then how do you explain this?: https://youtu.be/lTxaran0Cig?t=244

Comment: I would recommend using ``--add-data file.png;new-folder-or-use-. `` Instead of .spec file. It is much faster to learn. [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-add-data)

Comment: And actually, to access data files bundled by onefile, you neeed to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352931/14278613) to create a special function to access them. Btw, that method in the video is generally recommended.

Comment: Still, I don't understand why there's an error.

Comment: pleas provide the full error traceback, run the executable from cmd and see the full error, post it here then, the screenshot doesn't help at all, also you could provide a [mre] and the directory structure

Comment: @Matiiss I ran it from cmd but it gave no more error than that, it looked the same as in the screenshot, the game launches (black) and the error window pops up

Answer (score 0):

I read the comments of the video I watched (https://youtu.be/lTxaran0Cig?t=244), my font was apparently set to None, and when I set it to something it worked. But thanks for all the possible fixes

Comment: if this is the case, could you add the exact change you made to fix the issue? Otherwise someone else finding your question later seeing the same problem won't be able to use your answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.